# About returning STL containers data members without invoking copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, syntax, stl

I'd like to return an STL container of a private data member without invoking a copy constructor for the whole container.

This is what I did:

```
#include "point.h"
#include <deque>

class A {
    std::deque<Point> a;
public:
    const std::deque<Point>& getdq() const { return a; }
};
```

I call it in another class with

```
  A &a;
  ///a is initialized...
  auto dq = a.getdq();
```

But I see in the debugger that the `dq` has a different address than the one from class `A`, doesn't the `&` mean that it will pass by reference and not copy the whole deque?

Is there another way to pass an STL container without copying it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using `auto`, you end up with an object (not reference!) to a as dq. To have it as reference, modify your code to

```
const auto& dq = a.getdq();
```

Rules for `auto` type deductions can be found here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Other_contexts

Comment: So `auto` doesn't add a `const` and `&`? I didn't know that. It always just match the basic type without the surrounding stuff?

Comment: I have added the link to auto deduction rules to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

What you thought you wrote is

```
decltype(auto) dq = a.getdq();
```

This figures out the referenceness and the constness and so forth of the expression on the right hand side. However

```
auto dq = a.getdq();
```

strips references and consts. Another way to do the same thing you want is

```
const auto & dq = a.getdq();
```

This way you add the constness and referenceness back. This is the recommended way to do it.

Comment: Do you really want to see such code in a codebase you are supporting (but did not write?) I am talking about `decltype(auto) dq = a.getdq();`

Comment: @SergeyA you mean using `auto` is bad practice or `decltype()`?

Comment: @kuhaku, I mean, it would left me scratching my head and looking for getdq() declaration (for which I'd have to look for a definition) - a daunting task if a is, for example, the instance of a certain template - to understand what is returned and how should I treat it.